# Extend 2 buttons in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osDMN.png)I am a newbie to Tkinter. How can I extend 2 buttons in Tkinter? Here is the example image. :[I took screenshot of an app]

Thank you. Any help should be appreciated

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you used?

Comment: Extend? To where

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I mean grouping 2 buttons together. YOu can see the image

Comment: use [Frame](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_frame.htm)

Comment: How? Can you send ur code?

Comment: @Matiiss Can you help me?